# Optimized datastructure for arbitrary data

Tags: c#, .net, generics, data-structures

I need to store data in a manner similar to a dataset, i.e you should be able to access items/rows by number and then different fields of that item by field name.

What's keeping me up at night however is how much such a structure could be optimized from a  memory/casting/performance point of view. Some might see this as a uneccessary micro-optimization but please bear with me, see it as an exercise :) (and no, its not homework)

- I want to allocate as little memory per item as possible, that means optimally not even empty fields and as few instances as possible
- I want to avoid casting as much as possible, preferably using generics
- I want to be able to access fields in a nice, type-safe way, ie  items[0].Field<int>("fieldname") or  items[0].Field.Int("fieldname") (seems less elegant)
- I need to be able to access items by index and it needs to be an IEnumerable
- It needs to support concurrent reading/enumerating

if we start with  this (simplified example) structure:

```
public class Items : IEnumerable<Item>
{

    private List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

    public Item this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.items[index];
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<Item> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.items.GetEnumerator();
    }

}


public class Item
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> fields = new Dictionary<string, object> (StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    public T Field<T>(string fieldName)
    {
        return (T)this.fields[fieldName];
    }
}
```

Can you:

a)  Do something similarily with generics (or other way to avoid casting)? without storing additional fields, ie without storing one variable per type and field

b) Have the items class but eliminate the need for Item instances instead using a List directly in Items, and still be able to enumerate the class and access it's data using the Field method. I guess extensions methods somehow is the only way to go here.

One idea was to have a yield enumerator with a flyweight to avoid Item instances but I soon realized the potential problems that would mean if accessing items in parallel through things like PLINQ (or am I mistaken)

c) use some completely different approach?

Comment: do you have any performance wishes? read/write in O(1)/O(log n)/O(n)?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you create a separate class or member for *each* possible item-type that can be stored, I do not see how you are going to get around casting.

Certainly, having a member for each possible type is going to give you memory overhead as each item carries around weight with it (all the members that it is *not* a type of).  Footprint-wise, you've got the right idea with a string/object dictionary and a generic method to cast the desired object to its real type.